# Framer Motion Animation Not Firing in React Component

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, software-design

I'm currently facing an issue with implementing animations using the Framer Motion library within a React component. Despite my efforts, the animation I've set up doesn't seem to fire as expected.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { motion, usePresence, useAnimation } from 'framer-motion';

function Skill(props) {
    const scope = useRef(null); // Create a ref for the div element
    const animate = useAnimation();
    const [isPresent, safeToRemove] = usePresence();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPresent) {
            const enterAnimation = async () => {
                await animate.start(scope.current, { opacity: [0, 1] }, { duration: 0.5, delay: 0.2 });
            };
            enterAnimation();
        } else {
            const exitAnimation = async () => {
                await animate.start(scope.current, { opacity: [1, 0] }, { duration: 0.5, delay: 0.2 });
                safeToRemove();
            };
            exitAnimation();
        }
    }, [isPresent, animate, safeToRemove]);

    return (
        <div ref={scope} className='skill'>
            <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Skill;
```

I expected the animation to smoothly transition the opacity of the skill div from 0 to 1.

to make sure it was fully functional